# Can I use Apache web server in a chroot-ed environment on Gentoo? And how?

Tags: gentoo, chroot, apache-httpd

I just installed Apache for the first time on Gentoo. When I chroot into Gentoo from another OS (in this case Microknoppix) and try to start Apache (with `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`) I get the error `WARNING: apache2 is already starting`. If I try to stop it I get `ERROR: apache2 stopped by something else`. Apache functions normally when I run it under Gentoo without the chrooting.

I could probably get away with running Apache from within Gentoo itself and skip the chrooting entirely but I'm curious. Why is this happening and can I fix it?

I talked to someone earlier who thought it might be:

1. a problem with the with multiple programs trying to use the same pid file
  or
2. a problem with the way Gentoo handles chrooting.

But I don't know enough about either to discuss the subjects coherently myself.

Edit: Here are the commands I've been using to chroot into Gentoo, cribbed from [the install instructions in the Gentoo handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=6#doc_chap1):

`sudo mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/gentoo/etc/resolv.conf
sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/gentoo/proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/gentoo/sys
sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
sudo chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
env-update && source /etc/profile
export PS1="(chroot) $PS1"`

Comment: are you using the right environment variables? I remmeber that chrooting in gentoo involved a step of source /etc/profile and env-update or something like this. The relevant documentation is here https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=5 
Are you calling the system from the right linux?

Comment: @vfbsilva, I've added the commands I've been using to my original post so they can be critiqued, just in case there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo init scripts don't work well when Gentoo is running in a chroot.  Gentoo usually has inter-dependencies where apache won't start until 'net' has been started, and so on, and since none of these ran at startup (because Gentoo isn't the host system) things will generally be broken.  In the worst case, Gentoo might mess up your network settings or run fsck on your harddrive thinking that it isn't mounted yet.

Also, init scripts need to run as root.  If you aren't running it as root, it won't have permissions to modify the files that track a service's state.  If you are still running as root, beware that root can escape a chroot pretty easily.

I would suggest skipping the init script, and just pass apache a custom config file as you start it in the chroot.  Something like:

```
chroot /path/to/gentoo /usr/sbin/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

I also recommend running this command in the outer system with a supervisor program, like `perp` or `runit` or `s6`.  See http://skarnet.org/software/s6/why.html

It might also be that you need to have /proc mounted in the chroot.  Beware that if proc is mounted in the chroot, things in the chroot will be able to get a process list from the host system, which might be bad.  I assume you're doing this because you don't trust a script that you will be serving from apache?

Comment: I'm afraid you're giving me too much credit. The main reason I've been chrooting into Gentoo is because I got into the habit of doing it when I was setting it up and I thought being able to access my Gentoo install while working in another OS was a handy thing to do. Eventually Hearing you enumerate the risks has persuaded me that this might not be the smartest move.

Comment: I've also read that using chroot jails is a good security move and useful when installing software from source but I'll have to do more research before I use chroot jails, and for now I'll run Gentoo normally, outside of chroot.

Comment: I hesitate to criticize anyone's usage patterns, but it does sound like you might be doing it for the wrong reasons ;-)

I have found Gentoo chroots to be useful for two purposes: building custom linuxes by installing gentoo in a chroot and then using "mksquashfs" to build an image of only the necessary bits, and for running software that needs a completely different set of system libraries than the rest of my system.

Comment: The second case lets you do things like testing software with uClibc or musl-libc, and building static-linked binaries.  One time I also used a Gentoo chroot to get a graphical desktop on a console-only system.  This is how I learned that the Gentoo init scripts weren't likely to work, or would have unintended consequences.  In the end, running the chrooted binaries directly from scripts in the host system worked the best for me.

Comment: Oh, or if you want to run really new software on a really old system.  You can build things like the latest java or latest mysql (or apache) in a chroot, and then run them from the chroot, instead of the sometimes-impossible task of getting them installed in the host.